# Embed a Google maps heat map based on location survey data

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to code a Google map that will aggregate anonymous location data, input in the form of an online survey, into a public heat map?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can build a heat map using lat / long data, and display as a heat map using [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap).